# Exponential distribution probability

Tags: probability

Hi I got this question and I don't understand how can I resolve this. So there is the problem :

You have an internet connexion with your phone. The time of sending a message follow an Exponential distribution with an average of 15 seconds. But if the message take more than 15 second to be sent the message is not sent we have to resend the message. What is the Expected value of the number of try to send the message with success.

Comment: Have you already computed the probability that in one try the message is not sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $T$ denote the time of sending one/each message. Since it is given that $T$ is exponentially distributed and that $$E[T]=15=\frac{1}{λ}$$ you know that $T$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $λ=1/15$, i.e. $$T \sim \exp\left(λ=\frac{1}{15}\right)$$ Therefore, the probability that one/each single trial is successful is equal to $$P(T<15)=1-e^{\frac{15}{15}}=1-e^{-1}=0.632$$ Due to *independence* of different trials, the number $N$ of the trials until the first success is geometrically distributed with parameter $p=0.632$. Therefore (see f.e. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)) the expected value of $N$ is equal to $$E[N]=\frac1p=\frac{1}{0.632}=1.582$$

Comment: So much thanks :) . But I have no understand why 0.632 is the parameter of the geometrically distributed . if you can explain to me :) . EDIT : no sorry I have understand now :) Thank you very much !!

Comment: Ok, you are welcome! Good luck with it!